# What is the difference between: $\sqrt [4]{z^3}$ and: $4 \sqrt {z^3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I was working on math and I had to solve this problem:

**Rewrite the expression in radical form: $z^\frac{3}{4}$**

My first attempt was wrong: $4 \sqrt {z^3}$ 
I was confused as to why this was wrong until I saw the difference between the two solutions. This got me thinking: why are they different? (and in fact, I don't know how to say: $\sqrt [4]{z^3}$)

If you wouldn't mind, because I don't know what it's called, could you please explain the differences between the two solutions? (and maybe how to say the former ;) )

Thanks for you time!

Comment: is $z$ a complex number?

Comment: First one is the forth root of $z^3$ and the second one is four times the square root of $z^3$.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner no, $z$ is not a complex number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sqrt [4]{z^3}=z^{3/4}$ and $4 \sqrt {z^3}=4 \times z^{3/2}.$ i.e. the former is the fourth root of $z^3$ and the latter is multiplying the square root of $z^3$ by $4.$

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

it is $$4\sqrt{z^3}=4z^{3/2}$$ and $$\sqrt[4]{z^3}=z^{3/4}$$